# proving $DP=PB$ in a circle

Tags: geometry

Given a circle with chords $AB$ and $CD$ that are intersecting at the point $P$.

Need to prove that if $DB\cdot BC=AD\cdot AC$ then $DP=PB$.

I tried to prove that $P$ is the center of the circle by proportion of the given chords but failed.

Comment: HINT: Remember that, given any two chords $AB$, $CD$ intersecting in $P$, then $$AP\cdot PB = CP \cdot PD$$

Comment: @cjferes - thanks but as i wrote, that was my try which failed.

Comment: OK, give me some time to write an answer.

Comment: @abi: I think there is a typo, since $$BC\cdot BD = AC\cdot AD\Longleftrightarrow \color{red}{A}P=BP.$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - that's what it said in the question. so you think it's wrong?

Comment: @abi: yes, I think that the question should state $AP=BP$. $PB=PD$ does not necessarily hold in such a configuration. My proof is quite straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$AD\cdot AC = BC\cdot BD $ if and only if the two triangles $ACD,BDC$ have the same area, since $\sin\widehat{CBD}=\sin\widehat{CAD}$ in virtue of $\widehat{CBD}+\widehat{CAD}=\pi$. So $AD\cdot AC = BC\cdot BD $ if and only if the two points $A,B$ have the same distance from the $BC$-line (since the two triangles $ACD,BCD$ have the same base $CD$), i.e. if and only if $P$ is the midpoint of $AB$.

Comment: By your answer it seems that $BC\cdot BD = AC\cdot AD\Longleftrightarrow \color{red}{A}P=BP$. but that is strange because it's not written in the question i have.

Comment: @Abi: like I said above, I think your question has a typo. The only possible conclusion is $AP=BP$.

Comment: i see that, thanks.